# ValueError: Invalid MySQL identifier pandas to_sql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently trying to run pandas.to_sql() to push dataframe directly to table. Do I need to have table created beforehand?

I'm creating table dynamically using the following:

```
schema = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{}` (".format(self.out_tbl)
    for column in df.columns.tolist():
        if column == 'timestamp':
            schema += "`" + column + "` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL UNIQUE"
        else:
            schema += ",`" + column + "` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL"

    schema += ", PRIMARY KEY (timestamp)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;"
    return schema
```

Then,  return schema, and use the following to push dataframe to table:

```
data_to_tbl.to_sql(name=self.out_tbl, con=db, flavor='mysql', if_exists='append', index=False, index_label='timestamp')
```

With the following ablove 2 codes, I face the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid MySQL identifier 'cpu_ma100mlvnav001-FastFourierTransform Score'
```

Please note that, "**cpu_ma100mlvnav001-FastFourierTransform Score**" is 3rd columns in my dataframe, after 'timestamp' and 'cpu_ma100mlvnav001', and is a valid column in both dataframe and table. Also, since I'm creating mysql table's columns using dataframe's column names, this error shouldn't happen right? It happens only when column names mismatch happens right?

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: How do you create your MySQL table? which statement throws mentioned exception?

Comment: I returned schema after creating ir dynamically and did following to create table. **db.cursor().execute(schema)** and my 2nd line of code **data_to_tbl.to_sql()** throws exception.